# return columns vertically

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Let's say I have a simple select query that returns the following:

```
ID   Name1 Name2 Description1 Description2 Notes1 Notes2
1     A     B       AA              BB       AAA    BBB
2     C     D       CC              DD       CCC    DDD
```

and I want to return dataset as follows:

```
ID ColumnName    1st   2nd
1   Name           A   B
1   Description   AA   BB
1   Notes        AAA   BBB
2   Name           C   D
2   Description   CC   CC
2   Notes        DDD   DDD
```

Any way of doing that in sql server 2008-r2?
Looks like it's a job for PIVOT but a'm confused on how to achieve this with PIVOT

Comment: If the columns in your select query can be dynamic, not without dynamic SQL.  Does it have to be done with a SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this, assuming the values are static or not so numerous that patching it up with your actual values isn't too painful:

```
SELECT ID, 'Name' ColumnName, Name1 '1st', Name2 '2nd'
FROM YourTable
UNION
SELECT ID, 'Description' ColumnName, Description1 '1st', Description2 '2nd'
FROM YourTable
UNION
SELECT ID, 'Notes' ColumnName, Notes1 '1st', Notes2 '2nd'
FROM YourTable
```

Yet another great example of why data normalization is so important.